# Are there Elements such that this Set Relationship is true?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I have a set containing a set denoted by:

$\{\{?, ?\}\}$

And am looking to list elements, should there be any, such that:

$ \{\{?, ?\}\} \subseteq \{1, 2, \{3, 4\}\} $

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: {3,4} is an element of that set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

{{?,?}} is a set with a single element.  That element is a set with two elements.

{{?,?}} $\subset A$, is possible if we can make a subset of A the consists of precisely one element of A that is a set with two elements.  This is possible precisely if A has some elements that are sets containing two elements.  Any such element can be made to be the only element of a subset.

{1, 2, {3,4}} is a set with 3 elements the elements are: 1 which is not a set of all; 2 which is not a set at all; and {3,4} which is a set of 2 elements.

We can make 8 subsets of {1,2,{3,4}} but I won't list them all but ... oh yes, I will.  The 8 subsets are: $\emptyset$; {1}; {2}; {{3,4}}; {1,2}; {1,{3,4}}; {2,{3,4}}; and {1,2,{3,4}}.

Three of those subsets have precisely one element and only one of those subsets has precisely one element that is a set with two elements.

Solution is:

{{3,4}} $\subset$ {1,2,{3,4}};  {3,4} is the only element

If instead you had A={1, 2, {3,4}, {2,3} {1, 2, 4}{1,3,4}} then there would be 2 possible solutions:  {3,4} and {2,3} all the elements so that {{3,4}} and {{2,3}} are subsets of A.

Comment: Thank you. So for instance if I had a set $ \{?, ?\} $ would there be many subsets of $ \{1, 2, 3, \{4, 5\} \} $?

Comment: Not necessarily two elements in $\{?,?\}$: if $? = ?$ then it's a singleton. As it happens, the set on the right has no singletons, so it can only be $\{3,4\}$.

Comment: @BrianO Apologies for lack of clarity, each $?$ can represent any element, not two identical elements.

Comment: @GarethAllen-Stringer Particularly lousy notation, then :) You should probably explain that the two $?$"s are distinct — which you'd have to write $?\ne ?$ (what did I say about lousy notation). If normal variables were used, it would read $\{x,x\}$, and then clearly you'd be looking for singletons. If $\{x,y\}$ were used then $x=y$ would also provide possible solutions, unless you also stipulated that $x\ne y$.

Comment: That would be a subset with precisely two elements.  As there are four elements of the set and you are choosing 2 there 12 possible subsets with precisely two elements.

Comment: I didn't have a problem with the notation.  When I see a letter I assume it is a variable.  If I see a question mark or a dash or an asterisk, I assume it is simply a place holder.

Comment: @fleablood I only found 6: $\{1,2\}, \{1,3\}, \{1,\{4,5\}\}, \{2,3\}, \{2,\{4,5\}\}, \{3,\{4,5\}\}$. Are the remaining 6 $\{2,1\}, \{3,1\}, \{\{4,5\},1\}$ etc.?

Comment: The important thing to take from this is that a set can have a set as an element and, as such, should be treated the same as any other elements.  The elements *within* the set element are *NOT* elements of the bigger set and can not be considered as such.  If {?,?} $\subset$ {1,2,{2,3}} possible answers are {1,2}, {1,{2,3}} or {2,{2,3}}.  You can say {{hat, elephant},2} $\subset$ {1,2,3,{hat,elephant}} but you can *NOT* say {2, hat, elephant} $\subset$ {1,2,3{hat,elephant}} nor can you say {2, {elephant},{hat}} $\subset$ {1,2,3{hat}{elephant}}.

Comment: @BrianO Next time I use such notation I'll make that clear.

Comment: @fleablood I think it's 6 because it is $\subseteq$ and not $\subset$

Comment: Oops.  You are you right.  There are only 6.  There are 4 choices for the first element and 3 for the second but order does not matter so there are $4*3/2$ subsets with 2 elements.  I forgot to divide by 2.

Comment: @fleablood But even placeholders are used as if they're variables. E.g. if $f\colon \Bbb R^2\to \Bbb R$, if you write "the function $f(\bullet, 0)$" the meaning is clear; similarly, $f(\bullet, -)$ which just means $f$. But $f(\bullet, \bullet)$ is generally the function $x\mapsto f(x,x)$. Similarly for $?$. // That said, I assumed the two $?$s were *possibly* distinct, though I had no reason to assume they were required to be distinct (except by the only possible answer).

Comment: $\subseteq$ is not possible in this case because a subset with two elements can not be the whole set with 4.  In general that doesn't matter much.  When one claims that a set with 4 elements has $2^4 =16$ subsets they are including the entire set itself and they are also including the empty set.  The reason we know there are $2^4$ subsets is because for any element a half the subsets will contain a and half the subsets will not. Each additional element doubles the number of choices of subsets.

Comment: You definitely have a point.  I don't think there is (nor should there be) a formal convention of place holders. I kind of don't think of place holders as you do.  f(-,-) to me means the guy was to lazy to specify and each "-" can be filled in with whatever you want and doesn't represent a fixed value.  Otherwise how are "place holders" different from variables.  But on the other hand, an argument can be made that "place holders" have no place in formal mathematics.

Comment: My two cents and it's ambiguous but I see f(?,?) as meaning any two utterly unfixed values.  f(x,y) means x and y can each be anything but they are fixed but unknown values; it's possible x = y.  f(x,x) means x = x.  f(?,\*) implies because the used different notations that ? $\ne$ \*.  But it's very informal and ambiguous.  In general context will make it clear but "place holders" should probably be avoided.  I don't know why I simply assume ?,? meant two not necessarily equal values but I did.

Comment: If you're a set theorist then $0=\phi$ and $1=0\cup \{0\}=\{0\}$ and $2=1\cup\{1\}=\{0,1\}$ so  $2$ is a two-element member of $\{1,2,\{3,4\}\}.$

Comment: @user254665 that may be but if so the {{?,?}} is no longer simply a two-element member but a two element set were one of the elements isn't the empty set.  I think.  If we are going to be using set theory terminology we need a *lot* more work in rewriting this question which defeats its purpose.  ...

Comment: @fleablood So are you now saying that there are no subsets that're also equal to ($\subseteq$) the subset in the first question? Or are there the 6 discussed?

Comment: There are 4 elements so there are 16 subsets.  6 of them have exactly 2 elements. 1 of them has zero elements (the empty set), 4 of them have 1 element.  6 of them have exactly two, 4 of them have exactly 3, and 1 has all 4 elements (the set itself).  The sets with 2 elements are proper subsets.  Which is pretty much a given as they only have 2 elements and not all 4.